# How can I cast an @Binding in Swift

Tags: swift, casting, binding, slider, swiftui

In swift I can cast an Int to a Double with Int(doubleVariable).

But how can I cast a Binding < Double >  to a Binding < Int >  ?

Then I could pass an @Binding var intVar: Int to a function requiring a Double binding.

(The context of this is that I have an Int which I want to pass to a Slider in SwiftUI.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don’t think there’s a way to cast but you can create another Binding based on the first one:

```
import SwiftUI
var d = 1.0
// Create a Binding<Double> (for lack of another source)
var bd = Binding<Double>(get: { d }, set: { d = $0 })
// "Convert" to Binding<Int> by recreating another Binding
let bi = Binding<Int>(get: { Int(bd.wrappedValue) },
                      set: { bd.wrappedValue = Double($0) })
```

Comment: Thanks sas - would be nice if the SwiftUI library had an overload for Slider so that this was not needed. Cheers

Comment: Sorry this seems incomplete, can you post a complete working example. How do I set my binding double to bd with this code?

Comment: You'll have the `Binding<Double>` from some other source, `bd` is just created exactly to provide a full working example. The question was how to construct `bi`. Whatever you source of `Binding<Double>` is, substitute it in for `bd`.

Comment: @Cortado-J, I know this is a bit old but check out my answer here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/74356845/168179  It does exactly what you want--and for exactly the same purpose too--using generic bindings.