# SwiftUI abstract view for an array of different types of objects

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I want to make a list of two types of objects (MotorBikeRow and WithFootBikeRow will be these two slightly different row views of this list)

I am coming from Java and naturally I will create an abstract class called Bike. Such that I have a list of two (or more of course) types of objects :

```
@Binding var bikeList:[Bike]
```

But the problem is how to do this "abstract class" in Swift?
I am currently using a protocol called Bike that the two structs MotorBike and WithFootBike conforms to.

```
List {
    ForEach(...) i in {
         if bikeList[i] is MotorBike {
              MotorBikeRow(motorBike: $bikeList[i]) << error
         } else {
              WithFootBikeRow(withFootBike: $bikeList[i]) << error
         }
    }
}
```

But we immediately see a problem further, if these two views ask a binding.

```
@Binding var motorBike:MotorBike
@Binding var withFootBike:WithFootBike
```

So the question

1. How to cast the binding from Bike to MorotBike/WithFootBike?
   Of course I did used this "trick" : [How can I cast an @Binding in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58421913/how-can-i-cast-an-binding-in-swift) but there is memory leaks!
2. Is it the correct SwiftUI/Swift approach? Maybe I am completely wrong and too much influenced by "Java" that I do not see a more elegant solution?

Comment: I think it is not possible. But I only think

Comment: Are the Bike types classes or structs? Do the Row views need to mutate them?

Comment: @raynok They are struct